# Predicting Number of Records from GROUP BY WITH CUBE

Tags: sql, sql-server, math, permutation

**Step 1:** Run a query of the form

```
SELECT field1, field2, ..., fieldn, COUNT(id) 
FROM foo 
GROUP BY field1, field2, ..., fieldn
```

Record the number of columns, *n*, and record the number rows returned, *r1*.

**Step 2:** Change the query to

```
SELECT field1, field2, ..., fieldn, COUNT(id) 
FROM foo 
GROUP BY field1, field2, ..., fieldn 
WITH CUBE
```

Record the new number of rows returned, *r2*.

**Question:** Is there a formula/algorithm to compute/predict *r2*, given that we know *n* and *r1*?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of rows is the cross product of the number of unique values + 1 for each grouping column. You could get a rough estimate using:

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT field1)+1) * (COUNT(DISTINCT field2)+1)
FROM foo
```

Probably not as accurate as you need, but it's a start.

Comment: This does give a good upper bound for the value of *r2*. Seeing no other response/answer, I have taken the time to formulate a theoretical version of this question, hopefully we can get an answer that way: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86488/number-of-combinations-for-heteregeneous-slots